# Matrix algebra and evaluation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Can one evaluate this expression with only two matrix multiplications?

Matrices $A$ and $B$ are of the same square size, say $4\times 4$.  We want to evaluate:

$A^2+A*B*A$

I would write $A^2$ as $A*A$, but then $A*B*A$ is not equivalent to $A*A*B$, so I would need three multiplications, $A*A$ , $A*B$ and the product of $A*B$ multiplied with $A$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Difficult to solve an equation without an “$=$” sign

Comment: Did you mean to write $A^2=ABA$?

Comment: We also either omit a multiplication symbol, or use $\times$ rather than $\cdot$ in the context of matrices

Comment: You are missing the equation.

Comment: A and B are two matrices 4x4 , i just want to know if i can rewrite the given formular $A^2+A*B*A$ into a formular where i only need two multiplications instead of three

Comment: Matrix $A^2$ is not equivalent to Matrix A multiplicated with Matrix A?

Comment: $A^2+ABA=A(\mathbb 1+B)A$  only needs two matrix multiplications.

Comment: $A(1+B)A$ then i would need to calculate Matrix A with 1 and Matrix B with Matrix A and add them together?

Comment: I don't understand.  $\mathbb 1+B=M$ is an addition (much simpler).  And $AMB$ just needs $AM$ and then $(AM)B$, so two multiplications and an addition.

Comment: $A(1+B)A$ first i would need to calculate $1+B$ this would be M, then multiplicated M with A and the with A again?  I think i missunderstand something .. :/

Comment: What do you mean with $AMB$? $A(1+B)A$ is $AMA$ or am i missing something?

Comment: Your writing is very careless.  Order matters in matrix operations.  Step $1$:  Add the identity matrix to $B$ (a trivial operation), yielding a new matrix $M$.  Step $2$:  Compute $AM$  (one multiplication).  Step $3$:  Compute $(AM)A$ (another multiplication).

Comment: ok but why did you wrote $AMB$ ?

Comment: You understand, 234, that matrix multiplication is, in general, not commutative? So you're meant to multiply $M$ *on the left* by $A$, and then multiply the result *on the right* by $A$.

Comment: yes i understand this, i think your explanation is now clear, i just don't understand why you wrote $AMB$ at the top?

Comment: Right, I have a typo.  I should have written $AMA$.

Comment: Ahhh ok then i understand everything! Thank you sir :)

Comment: I think @lulu wrote $AMB$ but meant $AMA$. But if it did involve $AMB$, that would still take only two matrix multiplications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

We can write $$A+ABA=A(\mathbb 1 + B)A$$
where $\mathbb 1$ denotes the relevant identity matrix.

After the trivial matrix addition, we now only require two multiplies, namely $A(\mathbb 1+B)$ and then $(A(\mathbb 1+B))A$.